# jquery hide() works ramdonly

Tags: jquery, hide, vue.js

Recently, I've encountered a weird problem. I've written some jquery codes in a vue component's methods option. Everything is fine expected the jquery hide() function.

If I write my code like example1, the ".edit-box" disappears in a very short time and then appears (it flashs).

```
//my html
<p class="move-up-btn"  v-on:mousedown.stop="moveUpLib">...</p>

//example 1
Vue.component('...',{
    template:'...',
    methods:{
        moveUpLib:function(){
            (this).$parent.moveUpLib();
            $('.edit-box').hide();
        },
      }
    })
```

If I write my code like example2, the ".edit-box" disppears perfectly

```
 //example 2    
  Vue.component('auxiliary',{
    template:'#auxiliary',
    methods:{
        moveUpLib:function(){
            alert('hi');
            (this).$parent.moveUpLib();
            $('.edit-box').hide();
        },
     }
   })
```

So I wonder if it's something about the time to excute my code. And I changed my code like this. However, all that I get is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

```
  //example3
  Vue.component('...',{
    template:'...',
    methods:{
        moveUpLib:function(){
            (this).$parent.moveUpLib();
            setTimeout(function(){  $('.edit-box').hide(); }, 1000);
        },
      }
   })
```

I want to know

- 1 why example 1 does't work
- 2 why I can't use setTimeout inside the a
  Vue's methods option
- 3 How can I get the '.edit-box' disappear
  without alert

It would be greatful if anyone can help!

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you enclosing `this` in parenthesis? In general, there are many loose ends in these examples. What does `moveUpLib` do in the `$parent` element? What is `.edit-box`? And how come do you get a 404 error (Not found)? Are you fetching something via AJAX?

Comment: 1 There is no difference whether `this` is enclosed or not. I enclose it just because I want to stop my IDE from prompting error messages. 2 These examples are just a little part of my real code, which I think is too long and unnecessary to put all of them here. 3 `moveUpLib` in `$parent` does the real job of exchanging the position of the current library and the previous library (updating the database, etc..). 4 Each library component has a child component called `edit-box`. And each `edit-box` component has a class called `edit-box`.

Comment: 5 Whenever I put the `setTimeout` function inside Vue's methods, there will be a 404 error. There is no AJAX at all.  I'm curious too :)

Comment: Cantonese is my mother tongue ^^ Hope you enjoy HongKong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use jquery for this? Vue has it's own (and better :-P) way of dealing with this.

Vue's Philosophy (As well as angular's and reac's etc) is no touch the DOM directly as rarely as possible, and instad let the libarary change the DOM to fit the state/Data of a component.

html:

```
<textarea v-show="showEditBox" class="edit-box"><textarea>
```

JS

```
data: function () {
  return { showEditBox: true }
},
methods: {
  moveUpLib: function () {
    //other stuff...
    this.showEditBox = false // <= hides the textarea
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But in my case, there already exists so many interactions wirtten by jquey. Moreover, the component that triggles the "moveUpLib" function is a sibling of the "editBox" component. So it would be much easier for me to use jquery to hide the "editBox".  If I remember correctly, in the documentation of vuejs, it says vuejs works well with jquery. Lastly, I really can't figure out why jquey's hide() works only from time to time. It's so confusing .....

Comment: Ok, understoot your situation. I have no idea what the problem with `.hide()` is though.